Version of Dracula (Bram Stoker)
I'm looking for a version of Dracula by Bram Stoker (if that version exists):
In Chapter XI, Memorandum left by Lucy Westenra, there is the following sentence:

I kept my eyes fixed on the window, but the wolf drew his head back, and a whole myriad of little specks seemed to come blowing in through the broken window, and wheeling and circling round like the pillar of dust that travellers describe when there is a simoon in the desert.

I copied that from this site, which says it used this site as its source.
Now my question: Is there a version of the book that says "simoom" instead of "simoon"?
Background: When the NSA published the two blockciphers Simon and Speck in 2013, it provided some test vectors along with it. If you concatenate the plaintext values of the test vectors for Simon, you get "wheeling and circling round like the pillars of dust that travellers describe when there is a simoom in t". I thought maybe they changed it, but it seemed illogical to make it less similar to the name of the algorithm, unless it was a spelling mistake that they wanted to fix. So, I looked up the word in an online dictionary but apparently both spellings are correct.

Yes, there are multiple versions of the book that use the spelling simoom.
The earliest I could find was from 1899, in the sixth edition published by A. Constable and Co..



This appears on page 146.

The OED has citations (from other works) of simoom from 1790  and simoon from 1860. The word comes from the Arabic سموم (samūm), from a root meaning "to poison".
